# ggvis slider for bar plots

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

Am using R version 3.2.2. I am trying to create a bar plot with date on the x axis with a slider to control the number of date values displayed. I cannot figure what option helps me do this. I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  final_data %>%
    ggvis(~Date, ~work_left) %>%
    layer_bars(width = input_slider(min = 1, max = 10)) %>%
```

along with a host of other options including size which I found on other help sites. But none of them work.

My ui.r is a simple display of the chart in the main panel. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you use shiny, I think your solution would be to make users interactively  subset your data and draw a ggvis figure. As far as I know after tackling this question, `input_slider` does not take date objects; it requires numeric values. I thought `scale_datetime()` would be an option, but it did not really work.

Comment: @jazzuro, Yep. input_slider does not take date objects- which was the problem. Appreciate the response! thanks